# How to change meta tags in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, meta-tags, drupal-5

I am using some old version of drupal. I would like to change meta keywords and descriptions however they are not changeable from admin interface. I guess they cannot be changed by manually editing the files on the server. So, the question is: how to edit these meta tags? I am using Drupal 5 or 4(?). Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Go to the admin, look at the Status report. That will tell you the version of Drupal.

Comment: Nothing like Status report is there.

Comment: I don't know why you need to change the meta tags, but be aware that their effect on SEO is minimal, according to many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords), seems the D5 version is still available (while not maintaned anymore)